# parsing a csv file $INPUT, write to $OUTPUT, and prompt for user input all in a while loop - user NOT prompted

Tags: bash, csv, input, output, prompt

I have a problem, and I am pretty new to writing bash. I am parsing a csv file, checking for a few things. If a check is true, change the variable which will later be written to a file. I am reading an input file and outputting to a file as well, and If a certain argument checks True, then I want to prompt the user and pause the script until the user verifies the information matches (manual verification).

I have my most recent attempt which is not prompting. It just continues to read and write to the output. I am pretty sure because the output is going directly to my output file, but I do not know a way to direct the prompt to the terminal window which is where I am stuck.

```
INPUT=$TMPSAVE
IFS=,
[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }
while read cdwon cdwod manu_date hp_sn manu_sn wiped_by wiped_date checked_by disposition readonly
do
    for i in ${!allassigned[@]}
    do
            if [[ -n $manu_sn ]]
            then
                    if echo ${allassigned[i]} | grep -q $manu_sn
                    then
                            physicaldrive=${allassigned[i-1]}
                            disk=$(hpacucli ctrl slot=${SLOT} show config detail | grep -B 4 ${physicaldrive} | head -1 | awk '{print $NF}');
                            if [[ -n $disk ]]; then #proceed to wipe drive
                                    mount ${disk}${PRIMARY} ${MOUNT}
                                    if [ -e $DIR ]; then
                                    ####### the file exists, now what to do with it? Automatcially prompt user?
                                            cat $DIR > /dev/tty
                                            echo "Does the drive serial number (${allassigned[i]}) match what was provided from the database ($manu_sn)? (y/n)" > /dev/tty
                                            read
                                            if [ "$REPLY" == "Y" ] || [ "$REPLY" == "y" ] || [ "$REPLY" == "YES" ] || [ "$REPLY" == "yes" ]; then
                                                    checked_by=$username
                                                    checked_bydate=`date`
                                            fi
                                    fi
                            fi
                    fi
            fi
    done
    echo "$cdwon,$cdwod,$manu_date,$hp_sn,$manu_sn,$wiped_by,$wiped_date,$checked_by,$disposition,$readonly";
    continue;
done < $INPUT > $OUTPUT
```

Comment: the nested read is looking to stdin defined in your `done < $INPUT` for input. Look for examples of using file descriptors with read, i.e. `read -u 4`. And of course your `echo "Does the drive ..` is getting consumed in your redirection to stdout `> $OUTPUT`.  Good luck

Comment: @shelter - Nice! This is exactly what I needed, and you are correct about my echo statment as well! I ended up using a read -p:

`read -p "Does the drive serial number (${allassigned[i]}) match what was provided from the database ($manu_sn)? (y/n) " > /dev/null
                                                        if [ "$REPLY" == "Y" ] || [ "$REPLY" == "y" ] || [ "$REPLY" == "YES" ] || [ "$REPLY" == "yes" ]; then`

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own issue here. I found out that read by default is reading from the stdin. When I was trying to prompt for input it was using stdin, so the lines I was reading were technically the stdin input. If you want to read a file in a while loop with the method I have done you have to change the fd like so:

```
while read -u 6 column1 column2
do
.....body
done 6< $INPUTFILE
```

Key being the "6" which could be any arbitrary number.